# For loop to create tuples of adjacent elements

Tags: scala

I have a array

```
[1,2,2,3,4,6,2,4,6,8,2,3,5]
```

I want to iterate over this array using a for loop to get a collection of tuples of adjacent elements. How should I code in Scala?

Expected output :

`1-2|2-2|2-3|3-4|4-6|6-2|2-4|4-6|6-8|8-2|2-3|3-5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the output like `1-2|2-2|2-3|3-4|........` as you mentioned in your comment you can try following,

```
val arr = Array(1,2,2,3,4,6,2,4,6,8,2,3,5)

//here first separate array elements by - then whole array by | 
val str = arr.sliding(2).map(_.mkString("-")).mkString("|")

print(str)

//output
//1-2|2-2|2-3|3-4|4-6|6-2|2-4|4-6|6-8|8-2|2-3|3-5
```

Answer (score 2):

In scala you have `sliding` function for that.

```
scala> val arr = Array(1,2,2,3,4,6,2,4,6,8,2,3,5)
arr: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2, 3, 5)

scala> arr.sliding(2).foreach(tuple => println(tuple.mkString(" ")))
1 2
2 2
2 3
3 4
4 6
6 2
2 4
4 6
6 8
8 2
2 3
3 5

scala> arr.sliding(2).map(tuple => tuple.mkString("-")).mkString("|")
res10: String = 1-2|2-2|2-3|3-4|4-6|6-2|2-4|4-6|6-8|8-2|2-3|3-5
```

Comment: if I want to take the result into a stringbuilder and show like this "1-2|2-2|2-3|3-4|........" how to code? thx!!!!